# Javascript how to use class instead of id for dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

I have had another question similar to this and have tried to see if I could make it work in a similar way but I have been unsuccessful. What I have is two drop down menus one of them has its options created depending on what one you select on the first dropdown menu but I have run into an issue that I need to use the same menu twice on the same page which I thought may have worked but it didn't. I have realised on my own accord that it is because you can't have two objects with the same id. I'm wondering how I would make the script below work with a class instead of id of the form?

```
var i;
function fill_damage(i){
    var form1 = document.getElementById("form1a");
    document.form1aa.damage.options.length=0;
    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:
            form1.damage.options[0] = 
                new Option('Cracked screen','Cracked screen');
            form1.damage.options[1] =
                new Option('Cracked top case','Cracked top case');
            form1.damage.options[2] =
                new Option('Cracked bottom case','Cracked bottom case');
            form1.damage.options[3] =
                new Option('Broken keyboard','Broken keyboard');
            form1.damage.options[4] =
                new Option('Faulty touch pad','Faulty touch pad');
            form1.damage.options[5] =
                new Option('Hinge broken','Hinge broken');
            form1.damage.options[6] =
                new Option('Motherboard','Motherboard');
            form1.damage.options[7] =
                new Option('Hard drive','Hard drive');
            break;
        case 2:
            form1.damage.options[0] =
                new Option('Re image','Re image');
            form1.damage.options[1] =
                new Option('Wireless cert','Wirless cert');
            form1.damage.options[2] =
                new Option('Application','Application');
            form1.damage.options[3] =
                new Option('Hacked','Hacked');
    }
}


<form name="form1aa" method="post" id="form1a" >
    <select name="type" 
        onChange="fill_damage(document.form1aa.type.selectedIndex);">
        <option value="">Select Type</option>
        <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
        <option value="Software">Software</option>
    </select> 
    <select name="damage">
        <option selected="selected">Select Type First</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `document.getElementsByClassName()`

```
document.getElementsByClassName("yourClass")[0]; //first node with that class
```

Careful though as you can see here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#fivemethods, IE 7/8 does not implement this method. I would suggest to take a look at a framework like jquery to simplify all browsers compatibility headache!

Comment: is there a way to use jquery to create thesse dropdown menus or

Comment: Of course! You can also use regular javascript (like you did) with jquery. No problem here.

Comment: do u know where i could find the jquery version of what i am trying to do ?

Comment: Well you can use the function you have here and use `$('.formClass')` in jquery instead of your `document.getElementById("form1a");`

Comment: document.form1aa.type is undefined 
so i guess its from this part of the code
fill_damage(document.form1aa.type.selectedIndex);

Comment: Whoa, I thought IE8 had it. Did they have it in beta and then back out or something? Well, I'm glad I've avoided $('.someClass') simply out of IE6/7 habit. JQuery would have to parse every tag in a browser that doesn't have getElementsByClassName.

Answer (score 1):

Matthew, here is a demo for you. Hope I got what you wanted.

[Source](http://jsbin.com/ibatev/3/edit#javascript,html) | [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ibatev/3/edit#preview)

but as Allaire said this does not work on old IE. You can make custom getElementsByClassName(there are plenty on the web) or use jQuery if compatibility is an issue.

Comment: yes that how it orginally works but if u have 2 of them on the same page they dont work... do u know how to edit the index so that it works with classes instead of the name's

Comment: Updated demo with two sets of menus with classname.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `document.querySelectorAll()` or `document.querySelector()`.

```
document.querySelector(".yourClass"); //first node with that class
```

It is like a jQuery, but native in HTML5 browsers!

This is better than `document.getElementsByClassName` because IE 8 does support it!
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements

And then for the *not-supported*:

```
if(!document.querySelectorAll){
    document.querySelectorAll = jQuery;
}
```